# MySql Notifier not able to start/stop/restart MySql Service

Tags: mysql, windows-services, windows-7-x64, mysql-notifier

I've installed MySql 5.6 with Workbench and MySql Notifier.

I can start/stop the MySql Service ( Service name : MySql56 ) from Services.msc. But I'm not able to start/stop it from MySql Notifier. I'm having the following error.

[image]

I don't what's going on there. I can confirm that a service named "MySql56" is present and it starts/stops successfully from services.msc

My system is Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You must access to location: %APPDATA%\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\settings.config (C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\settings.config) 
and change ServiceName to MySQL56 in settings.config file

See this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSXKl.png

Comment: Yes! This fixed it -- I had to change from mysql56 to MySQL56 -- and I had to restart the MySQL Notifier after saving the settings.config file. Thank you!!!

Comment: Same issue on MySql Notifier 1.1.7

Answer (score 34):

I had this same issue a few days ago but I figured out a way to fix it, hopefully it works for you as well:

right click on MySQL Notifier -> Actions -> Manage Monitored Items

highlight the MySQL56 entry and click the delete button

click the add button -> windows service, scroll down the list till you find MySQL56, highlight it and click ok

you can now close the menu and you should be able to start/restart/stop your server as before

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked! In my case I wasn't able to implement the other method because there was no `ServiceName` element in settings.config, and I wasn't sure were it should be added.

Comment: @user4823003 , But this solution is not working in my system.Even settings.config file is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your MYSQL service is running or not. Starting below highlighted service solved my problem:

[image: MYSQL Service]

To start this service in windows go to `Control Panel -> Administrative Tool -> Services`

Comment: this worked for me. Actually service was not started automatically by OS.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to install a new server again using MY SQL installer